# Google maps Custom marker - svg

Tags: google-maps, svg, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to add custom marker - SVG of donut shape. Following is the link of fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/jfx2uqws/7/

Code:

```
let map;

let latlng_statue = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25);

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: latlng_statue
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  let data = [{
    fill:25,
    color:"#80e080"
},{
    fill:25,
    color:"#4fc3f7"
},{
    fill:25,
    color:"#9575cd"
},{
    fill:25,
    color:"#f06292"
}]
let doughnut = document.querySelector("#map-canvas"),
svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg"),
filled = 0;
svg.setAttribute("width","80px");
svg.setAttribute("height","80px");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 100 100");
doughnut.appendChild(svg);
data.forEach(function(o,i){
  var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","circle"),
  startAngle = -90,
  radius = 30,
  cx = 50,
  cy = 50,
  strokeWidth = 15,
  dashArray = 2*Math.PI*radius,
  dashOffset = dashArray - (dashArray * o.fill / 100),
  angle = (filled * 360 / 100) + startAngle;
  circle.setAttribute("r",radius);
  circle.setAttribute("cx",cx);
  circle.setAttribute("cy",cy);
  circle.setAttribute("fill","transparent");
  circle.setAttribute("stroke",o.color);
  circle.setAttribute("stroke-width",strokeWidth);
  circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray",dashArray);
  circle.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset",dashOffset);
  circle.setAttribute("transform","rotate("+(angle)+" "+cx+" "+cy+")");

  svg.appendChild(circle);

  filled+= o.fill;

})

var foreignobject = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","foreignobject"),
  clsName="node",
  x="40",
  y="42",
  width="20",
  height="20";
  foreignobject.setAttribute("class",clsName);
  foreignobject.setAttribute("x",x);
  foreignobject.setAttribute("y",y);
  foreignobject.setAttribute("width",20);
  foreignobject.setAttribute("height",20);

  let spanEl = document.createElement("span");
  spanEl.setAttribute("style", "font-size: 10px;");
  let fontColor = document.createElement("font");
  fontColor.setAttribute("style", "color: red;");

  let iconEl = document.createElement("i");
  iconEl.setAttribute("class","fa fa-cloud");
  fontColor.appendChild(iconEl);
  spanEl.appendChild(fontColor);

  foreignobject.appendChild(spanEl);
  svg.appendChild(foreignobject); 

let s = new XMLSerializer();
let str = s.serializeToString(svg);

let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng_statue,
        map: map,
        title: 'donut',
        icon: { url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(str), scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50) },
    optimized: false
    });
    } 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Problem is - I'm trying to add icon in the middle of the donut. But its not getting displayed.

So, looking for the solution or if any other easy way to achieve the above thing - svg multi color donut with icon in between.

Comment: foreignobject is case sensitive and must be written as foreignObject in createElementNS

Comment: Added this change, but still its not working for me. Icon added is still not getting displayed. : https://jsfiddle.net/u5zf9gtk/1/

Comment: The icon is really tiny and is in the top left corner. Your browsers web debugging tools can show you where it is.

Comment: yes I am able to see it but only if am taking that SVG code and run it somewhere else in any random html page . But on google map its not showing the Icon. https://jsfiddle.net/u5zf9gtk/8/ .. and Thanks Robert for replying on this issue.